# ReactJS this.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I try to understand exmple from ReactJS:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {date: new Date()}; 
    this.date = new Date(); // why not just this.date
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App Hello, {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h1>
        <h2>{ this.date.toLocaleTimeString() }</h2> //same result
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```

Why should I use **this.state.date** instead of just **this.date**?
For update this.date, I also may use setter, something like setDate().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an property will not be changed during your component lifecycle generally you're right - result will be the same. But if you're going to change this property then your react component will not be aware of these changes if you decide to use `this.someProperty` because after the initial mounting React component is re-rendered only if `setState` (which updates `this.state` object) is called, parent component is re-rendered or `forceUpdate` is called. So if you want your component to be re-rendered when you change some property it should be stored in state object and updated using `setState`. Back to your example:  if you use  `setDate` to update `this.date` your component will not be aware of this action and will still show old value. If you use this:

```
this.setState({date: '2016'})
```

it will update `this.state.date` and React will be aware of this change and will re-render your component to show current date value.

Answer (score 0):

this.state allows you to maintain state of the component during component lifecycle. It dosen't make any sense if you use this.state and never changed during component lifecycle.

to declare state you have to use:

```
this.state = {
  'key': 'initial value'
}
```

to update state you have to use:

```
this.setState({
  'key': 'your updated value'
});
```

It is bad practice to update state like this. this.state.key = somevalue.

Whenever your set any state of your component the render method will get called again to re render the component with updated value.

So for your question if your date is not going to change at any stage of component lifecycle then you can use this.date instead of this.state.date.
If it is changing and you want to use updated value then you can use this.state.

Answer (score 0):

to initialize the state variable you just need to do

```
this.state = { `state variable name` : `initial value` }
```

And if you want to change/assign new value to the state variable, then 
you have to do

```
this.setState( {`state variable name` : `new value`} )
```